# Chinese characters

Tags: cjk, xecjk

In an article mostly in English in one quotation there are a few words in Chinese characters. Using the `xecjk` package for `xelatex` they mostly get displayed, but two of the word contain characters getting replaced by an F in a box. Now not knowing Chinese I don't really understand how to proceed, maybe change the font, or maybe do something about the characters? The default font seems to be Fandol, but I'm getting a message of it missing CJK script, although I'd guess that's not really related to my problem:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'FandolSong-Regular' does not contain script 'CJK'.
*************************************************
```

Anyway, here my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}%this font is not installed, but it seems xeCJK happily uses a default.
\begin{document}
This is a document mostly in English, but containing a few words in Chinese characters.

大豊饒諸衆善法

瞋怒
\end{document}
```

Compiling to:

[image: Chinese characters sample]

Comment: I cannot tell why the default font misses that two characters. If there are less than, say, 100 characters, use `CJK` package with LaTeX is good enough. By good enough I mean that it is packed with several default font for traditional and simplified characters.

Comment: If it really is a matter of a few charackter, you might consider just including a screenshot of the word. Not really pretty, but it might do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characters 豊 and 瞋 are rather uncommon in everyday use so I guess that's why they are not included in the default font. You need to pick a font that has these two characters. Personally I prefer `Microsoft JhengHei` for traditional Chinese and `Microsoft YaHei` for simplified, these two fonts should be available if you are using Windows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft JhengHei UI}

\setCJKfamilyfont{YaHei}{Microsoft YaHei UI}

\begin{document}
    This is a document mostly in English, but containing a few words in Chinese characters.

    大豊饒諸衆善法

    瞋怒

\CJKfamily{YaHei}

    大豊饒諸衆善法

    瞋怒
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I'd like to use a font under a free license, preferably included with TeX Live or Ubuntu. Any suggestion?

Comment: @muk.li I don't use Ubuntu so I am not sure what fonts are available. From a quick search it seems `WenQuanYi Micro Hei` should work. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WenQuanYi

Comment: @muk.li BTW, the sentence you used seems from 大藏經, in that case 豊饒 should actually be 豐饒. Note 豊 and 豐 are not the same.

Comment: Wiktionary tells me it's a simplified Japanese character, which indeed seems strange for an 8th century Buddhist text. I'll check that, thanks.

Comment: @muk.li I see what's going on here, 豊 and 豐 are separated characters in Chinese with different meaning and pronunciation (but they do have subtle connection etymologically speaking), but Japan adopted 豊 as the simplified version 豐, whilst China adopted 丰. The confusion happens probably because you are using Japan version of 大藏經

Comment: o.k., so the first line displays fine replacing this one character. What about the 瞋 in the second line? Just a rare old character unfortunately not included in the default font?

Comment: @muk.li 瞋怒 is an older way to write it, today it is more common to see 嗔怒 and I suspect that it might do with default font. Again 瞋, 嗔 together with 謓 have all kinds of subtle connections.

Comment: Looks like \setCJKmainfont{AR PL UMing CN} gives good results.